# How spring data JPA decides to call entityManager.persist(…) or entityManager.merge(…) method

Tags: spring, spring-data

When entityManager.persist(…)-Method is called and when a entityManager.merge(…) is called in spring data jpa. According to documentation:
**If the entity has not been persisted yet Spring Data JPA will save the entity via a call to the entityManager.persist(…)-Method, otherwise the entityManager.merge(…)-Method will be called...**

So how does spring data determines whether the entity is persisted or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

here is the impl of `save` method(in `SimpleJpaRepository`):

```
/*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#save(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

So it looks at `entityInformation.isNew(entity)`. Implementation of this method is(in `AbstractPersistable`) :

```
public boolean isNew() {

        return null == getId();
    }
```

So it decides based on id field

Comment: This is mainly correct, but if you use `@Version ` it must be included as well.