# How to make spring data jpa call entityManager.persist(…) method during save?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am new to JPA

I want to insert a record into the database (Insert and not Update).

But when I use repository.save() method, then it acts as an Update query if the record is already present.

How to do only insert in this case(throw an exception if record already exists)?

[How spring data JPA decides to call entityManager.persist(…) or entityManager.merge(…) method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573023/how-spring-data-jpa-decides-to-call-entitymanager-persist-or-entitymanager-me)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `exists()` method of the repository and call `save()` only if the record does not exist.

Comment: How can I use exists() method on an Entity class having composite primary key(Embeddable id)?

Comment: I think you will need to write your own @Query for that. Use a `SELECT COUNT ` and check the equality of all fields of the ID class in the `WHERE` part.